# Configure Oracle VM VirtualBox guest to use LAN only

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I'm setting up a Windows XP guest machine on my Ubuntu 22.04 installation using Oracle VM VirtualBox.

Since Windows XP has been considered fairly unsafe to be accessible via the internet, I want to configure my VM to be able to access my local network (LAN), but not to connect to the internet itself.

Which network adapter do I have to take for this and what do I have to configure there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a feature Oracle VM VirtualBox provides. However, it can be arranged through other means:

- The naive approach would be to not configure a gateway on the virtual machine. Without a gateway, the machine doesn't know where packets destined outside the LAN will need to go, so it won't be able to connect to the internet. If a host on the internet would connect to the machine, it wouldn't be able to send a reply, greatly decreasing the attack surface.
- A more robust approach would be to set up a firewall on the host machine. You can configure the firewall on the host to allow packets from the VM to the local network, but not to the internet (and vice versa).
- An even more advanced approach would be to have the VM in a seperate network/VLAN and set up a seperate firewall and IDS/IDP appliance/VM. This way you can control ALL traffic in and out of the VM and even scan it real-time for suspicious activity. How to set this up is beyond the scope of this question (and probably even beyond the scope of SuperUser).

If it'd be me, I'd do anything to avoid using XP altogether (use compatibility mode, etc.). If that's impossible, I'd go for option two, if you're able to monitor the VM any time it's running. If you need to run a server on it, think about implementing option three.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I guess I'll go forward as you said and set up the firewall for said use.